# Return FALSE After Throwing Exception

Tags: php

I've made it a habit to include `return false;` after throwing an Exception in a PHP function, even though the [PHP docs state](https://www.php.net/exceptions):

> When an exception is thrown, **code following the statement will not be executed**, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching `catch` block. If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "`Uncaught Exception ...`" message...

However, I still feel that it is safer to `return false` in case there is no `catch` block and error reporting is turned off.

Am I crazy to believe this?

Comment: Yes, you're crazy :)  If there's no corresponding `catch`, the exception will result in a fatal error and the `return` still won't be executed.

Comment: Yes. Yes, you are :p It's like the stories of people who write `var x = 7; var x = 7; // just to make sure it's set properly` ;)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Nice, same second XD

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yeah, I did. New main project, new identity ;)

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for your input everybody!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no `catch` block, and an exception is thrown. The PHP script will stop executing immediately.

So yes, you are crazy and there is no point in the `return false`.